# Led and buzzer at the same time in python is it not possible?

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to get the buzzer and led to go off at  the same time? I am new to python. Is it really not possible?

```
def Alarm():
  GPIO.output(GPIO_ALARM, GPIO.HIGH)
  time.sleep(0.05)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_ALARM, GPIO.LOW)
  time.sleep(0.1)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_ALARM, GPIO.HIGH)
  time.sleep(0.1)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_ALARM, GPIO.LOW)
  time.sleep(0.1)


def Led():
  GPIO.output(GPIO_LED,GPIO.HIGH)
  time.sleep(0.5)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_LED,GPIO.LOW)
  time.sleep(0.1)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_LED,GPIO.HIGH)
  time.sleep(0.1)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_LED,GPIO.LOW)
  time.sleep(0.1)


try:

  while True:

    distance = measure_average()
    print("Distance : %.1f" % distance)
    time.sleep(1)


    if distance < 100:
      Alarm()
      Led()
```

I am here to learn.. Please help me!

Video of the problem [Result I get](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KTyLDfYfjcEcG6Bwo-mkLd5HUvZPRjkD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is tagged multithreading, but there isn't any multithreading in the code.  The Alarm and Led functions are called sequentially.  In order to have them go simultaneously, you either need multithreading, or rewrite your functions to have a single Alarm_and_Led function, that does all the things at the same time.  A GPIO output is nearly instant, but the sleep() timings may have to be reworked.

Comment: Thanks Brian! A rewiring on the breadboard was the easy solution for me. But I need to read up on multithreading for the future.

Answer (score 0):

This problem about threading and multitasking in easiest way you can manage and share time between process by your self.
here is an example to do this in `AlarmWithLed` function:

```
def AlarmWithLed():
    GPIO.output(GPIO_ALARM, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_LED,GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_ALARM, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_LED,GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_ALARM, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_LED,GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_ALARM, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_LED,GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.1)

try:

  while True:

    distance = measure_average()
    print("Distance : %.1f" % distance)
    time.sleep(1)


    if distance < 100:
    #   Alarm()
    #   Led()
        AlarmWithLed()
```